# Groovy script executable

Tags: shell, groovy

I'd like to make my groovy script portable and I inserted in the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
```

The problem comes up when I run the script outside of its directory, it can't find libraries. I come from python world and all imports in python resolving relatively script's path. In groovy it seems I have to specify -classpath but I can't do that in the first #! line.

Any suggestions how to resolve it?

Comment: how about:

#!/usr/bin/env groovy -cp my:class:path

Comment: I wouldn't like to hardcode my:class:path there and it's impossible to use something like #!/usr/bin/env groovy -cp `dirname $0`

Answer (score 10):

If the libraries are stored in a Maven repository that is accessible wherever you want to run it, one solution would be to use [Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) to grab the libraries.

This provides several benefits:

1. You don't have to worry about the classpath at all
2. You don't have to distribute the libraries — just make sure Groovy is available on the client
3. Libraries are downloaded just once, so even if you upgrade the application, you only have to redistribute the `.groovy` file.

A simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab(group='commons-io', module='commons-io', version='2.3')
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

... use FileUtils like normal ...
```

There's a lot of existing libraries available on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/) already.

Even if you have non-public libraries, it's relatively easy to put your own [libraries into a local / private repository](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape#Grape-AddyourlocalMaven2repository).

Comment: Actually it's not libraries but part of application - just application packages, classes, etc...

Comment: You could put all of that into a single Jar.

Comment: Possibly? A JAR is just a ZIP with a manifest.  Otherwise, if you already have a bunch of loose files, why don't you just wrap your Groovy application in a shell script, and run that instead?

Comment: That's an option. Just it would be one extra file that runs the groovy script. As I said I came from python world and that wouldn't happen there. I was just curious how it worked in groovy.